# Click anywhere to close the window with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

everyone. I'm sorry that my English is not very good. Please forgive me if there is any mistake in the description.

My problem is that I made a design where clicking the yellow button would bring out the white menu, but clicking a line anywhere in the white menu would close the menu again

So far, something has been tried

However, it becomes impossible to even click the yellow button at the beginning. I am thinking that because the yellow button is also in the document, he decides to close the menu as well. How can I realize that if I click the yellow button, there will be a white menu, and if I click the white menu, I can close the menu?

Thank you for watching my question, and thank you for your help.

This is my code

```js
$(function(){
   $('.btn').on('click',function(){
      $('.demo').toggle();
   });
});


//It was my attempt but it didn't work
// $(document).on('click',function(){
//     $(this).find('.demo').css('display','none');
//   })
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ef3473;
}
.nav{
  background-color: #2486b9;
}

.btn{
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbda41;
}

.menu{
  position: relative;
}

.demo{
  display:none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding:20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <button href="javascript:;" class="btn">
           <a href="javascript:;" class="menu">選單</a>
           <ul class="demo">
              <li><a href="javascript:;">選單1</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;">選單2</a></li>
           </ul>
           </a>
     </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you could check for the contain property, the click function provides you with the `event` parameter which includes the clicked `target` and then you check if the target is or not your element, something like this can do the trick:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.demo').toggle();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.contains($('.demo')[0])) {
        $('.demo').toggle();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ef3473;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #2486b9;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbda41;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.demo {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav">
    <button href="javascript:;" class="btn">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="menu">選單</a>
      <ul class="demo">
        <li><a href="javascript:;">選單1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">選單2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Reference** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Comment: Thank you for your help, although I am not quite clear about the meaning of [0] in $('.demo')[0], then I will go to further study, thank you again for solving my problem.

Comment: When you use `CSS classes` there might be multiple elements in the DOM with the same class so with `$('.demo')` you get a list of all the elements with that class, `$('.demo')[0]` just checks the first element

Comment: I see, Daniel Rodriguez Meza really appreciate your help and telling me so much!
I'm sorry ~ I'm from Taiwan and my English is not very good. If it's not good, please forgive me.